# What application will give me a calendar with a year view?

Tags: application-development, calendar

Most applications have month or week or agenda view but I'm looking for something that can give me a one year spread.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the command prompt try:

```
cal -y 2013
```

(You have to install the bsdmainutils package if it doesn't work.)